# How to pass query string with routes in laravel 5.4

Tags: query-string, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5.4. I want to use query string like below:

```
tempsite.com/lessons?id=23
```

For getting this how routes are to be modified. It is possible to give route in the following way.

```
Route::get('lessons/id={id}', ['as' => 'lessons.index', 'uses' => 'Lessons\LessonController@index']);
```

But adding '?' is not getting for me. Please help us to provide a solution as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using resourceful controllers, your routes are all handled for you so you would simply put

```
Route::resource('lessons', 'Lessons\LessonController');
```

You can then use route model binding to bind the model instance which matches that particular ID.

```
Route::model('lesson', Lesson::class);
```

This would be done in your RouteServiceProvider.

I would also suggest having a good read of the following documentation on the laravel website https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing. It provides really good insight in to how routes work and how they should be structured.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tempsite.com/lessons?id=23
Pass it like this tempsite.com/lessons/23
and in the route

```
Route::get('lessons/{id}', ['as' => 'lessons.index', 'uses' => 'Lessons\LessonController@index']);
```

to get the id in your controller, write your function like this

```
public function index($id)
{
    //do anything with $id from here
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Although in this specific case it would be better to pass it as a meaningful URL, there's time where querystrings are still better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define query string parameters in your routes. You can return query string parameters in your controller like so:

URL example: tempsite.com/lessons?id=23

```
public function lessons(Request $request)
{
    $request->get('id'); // Using injection
    Request::get('id'); // Using the request facade
    request()->get('id'); // Using the helper function
}
```

You could even validate the parameter:

```
public function lessons(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['id' => 'required|integer']);
}
```

Note: If you want to make the URL not accessible if the ID is omitted, see @DarkseidNG answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to inform laravel to accept query stringed requests on my route by affixing the url with a forward slash, like so

```
 // web.php
 Route::get('/path/', "Controller@action");
```

With the above, `mysite/path?foo=bar&name=john` does not throw 404 errors.